# Opening two unique mysql connections?

Tags: php, mysql

I have two separate databases and I want to open a connection to both of them at the same time, they both have the same login details so I used the fourth parameter in the `mysql_connect` function so I could use both.

As such..

```
$db1 = mysql_connect('host','user','pass',true);
mysql_select_db('db1', $db1);
$db2 = mysql_connect('host','user','pass',true);
mysql_select_db('db2', $db2);
```

When I use the `$db1` resource in a `mysql_query` it works fine, however when I use `$db2` it still tries to use the `db1` database.

I know I can reference databases such as `db.table` but just wondering why this doesn't work?

Comment: @Col.Shrapnel - what are you going on about?

Answer (score 1):

If you don't provide an argument for the [`new_link`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php) parameter, an existing link will be returned; however, if you *do* but SQL safe mode is enabled, then it is ignored:

> `bool new_link`
>
> If a second call is made to mysql_connect() with the same arguments,
>   no new link will be established, but instead, the link identifier of
>   the already opened link will be returned. The new_link parameter
>   modifies this behavior and makes mysql_connect() always open a new
>   link, even if mysql_connect() was called before with the same
>   parameters.
>
> In [SQL safe mode](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.sql.safe-mode), this parameter is ignored.

This could be the case.

Comment: I'm already passing `true` for the `new_link` parameter as you can see in my code above.